# Binding directive instances through a common property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to share a property between two instances of the same directive.
Here is a plunkr to help me explain what I mean.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wsrSxq?p=preview

The left position of the two boxes should be linked together through the `scope.left` value
but if I $watch for changes it won't work as I suspect the directive influences itself in a loop.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is missing is a call to `scope.$apply` so that the watch gets triggered. Since an event handler that changes a scope value does so from 'outside' of the app, `$apply` is needed to notify Angular of the change. Uncomment the two commented lines and change:

```
scope.left = newX;
```

to

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.left = newX;
});
```